# Under what circumstances does @SpringBootTest need the optional "classes" element?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, junit4, spring-boot-test

See [this doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) first.
I have an app set up with several test classes extending an abstract class like so:

```
    public class TestClass extends AbstractClass {

        @Autowired
        private ClassToTest classToTest;
        ...
        //Some tests
```

And the abstract class is set up like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initialize() {
        //Section 1
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestSpringConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public SomeBean someBean() {
            //Section 2
        }
        ...
```

Every time I ran my tests this failed and I can see a breakpoint in section 1 hit but not in section 2. I tried several different setups like this with extending/not extending and such, moving the `@SpringBootTest` to my `TestClass`, etc., no luck. Then I happened across [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6768) and tried this with what you see above:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes=AbstractClass.TestSpringConfiguration.class)
```

and it works!

However, this leaves me wondering, why *does* it work? I see many examples online where they use a static inner class with `@TestConfiguration` and don't have the `classes` element set. In fact, I have hardly seen the element mentioned much at all other than the docs. Now here's the real kicker: I have a separate app set up identical to the one in question in virtually every way, yet it does work without the element.

Does anybody have a clue as to what might affect this? Is this not supposed to be automatic?

I'm on Spring Boot 1.5 (not my choice, and yes I know the doc linked above is 2.x), Spring 4.3, and JUnit 4.

Comment: See the quote from same issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6768#issuecomment-367154913

Comment: That's how I figured out that I needed the `classes` element, but that doesn't explain to me *why* when in seemingly identical situations I don't need it.